# Can I add class with only CSS?

Tags: css, class, inheritance

I'm wondering if I can somehow "inherit" a class property to some elements such as body, like:

```
.playfont{font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;}

body{.playfont}
```

I know I can do this with JavaScript or LESS, or even adding the class in HTML markup, but is there any pure css way for this?
Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's a selling points of lesscss, so no wonder it's not present in vanilla css.

Comment: Why not just do `body, .playfont{font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;}`

Comment: Why don't you want to use LESS? Or is this just an educational question

Comment: @j08691 it's pretty much same, yes. thanks.

Comment: @DannyHearnah I don't know how to setup LESS in web server and I think it would slow things down. But apparently I'm going towards there :)

Comment: @marvin it won't really slow anything up, as it will only compile the CSS when it's modified, it wont be compiling a version everytime someone visits your webpage - alternatively you could just run LESS locally (where you write your CSS) and everytime you save it, it will automatically compile the .css version to be uploaded.

Answer (score 4):

The closest you can come with pure CSS is like this:

```
.playfont,
body { /* .... rules here */ }
```

Other than that, you'll need a preprocessor. And the way I described above gets messy pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can do like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
h1, .test { 
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Test</h1>
<h2 class="test">Test</h2>

</body>
</html>
```